# value in column not being updated after having trigger on it

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a trigger that will sum my price after adding values to `Done services` table. I am not sure why it is not adding the price to the service table, whenever I insert an item to `Done services` that has price in it. Can someone help me with this one?

Service table

```
service_id (PK)
service_name
```

Payment table

```
payment_id (PK),
service_id (FK),
price
```

Done services table

```
done_jobs_id (PK),
service_id (FK),
price,
quantity
```

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION sum_payment() RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE payment
        SET price = price + new.price WHERE service_id = new.service_id;
    RETURN NEW;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER sum_payment AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON done_services
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION sum_payment();
```

Comment: Something to think about, is the database setup to auto-commit updates?

Comment: Do you have anyy trigger before or after update on table payment ? Are you sure there are one or more rows in table payment which match with the inserted or updated row in table done_services ? Be carefull in case of update row in table done_services, you are going to double count the service price. In case of update, payment.price = payment.price + NEW. price - OLD.price

Comment: @Edouard is `before` trigger needed on payment?

Comment: Your description, '...adding the price to the service table, ...' does not match your code which is updating `payment` table. Not that there is price to update in the`service` table. FYI, `RETURN NEW;` does nothing as the return value is ignored in `AFTER` triggers. To make that clear use `RETURN NULL;

Comment: @AdrianKlaver should I use the `RETURN` at all? Also, I've realised that if price in `payment` is null at first, the trigger wont work on it, unless I change the price to >= 0, what causes that?

Comment: A trigger has to `RETURN` something so you will need to use `RETURN NULL`. Adding to `NULL` will return `NULL`: `select null + 1; NULL`. Try: `price = COALESCE(price, 0) + new.price`. `select coalesce(null, 0) + 1; 1.`  See [COALESCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL).

Comment: Other option is to have `done_services.price` have a  `DEFAULT` value of `0` so it gets 'seeded`' with a `0` on `INSERT` of row into `done_services`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver it started to work after I made default value to `0`, how is that possible that it doesn't work when the price has `null` value? Also I tried making update statement like t his `SET price = price + NEW.price - OLD.price` but it keeps adding new price to old price, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I showed you `NULL` math in previous comment and a solution. There is no `OLD.*` in an `INSERT` only `NEW`, so if you are using it in `sum_payment` it is  erroring out on inserts. You need to spend some time here [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).